# Future perfect tense by example

Tags: future-perfect

Are the following sentences correct? Please correct me, if they are wrong.

"I hope I'll have <strike>migrated</strike> immigrated to Australia when year 2018 will start."

"I hope I'll have <strike>migrated</strike> immigrated to Australia in the next 3 months."

"I hope I'll have <strike>migrated</strike> immigrated to Australia by the time year 2018 starts."

I look forward to <strike>here</strike> <strike>hear</strike>  hearing from you soon.

Comment: I look forward to **hearing** from you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all three of these are future perfect. The clue words are *will have*, though the first of these is contracted with *I* into *I'll*.

They are also all grammatically correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, and I am really embarrassed because of 'here' :)))

Comment: No prob. I edited my answer, so there is now no record of it! *laughs evilly*

Comment: Another question: Which tense should/can I use after 'Future Perfect' tense to show the time? Simple Future, Simple Present, or ...

Comment: I think that simple present would be best. The third example sentence you gave is certainly preferable to the first.